# How to add an append symbol in a subprocess in python

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, subprocess

I have the following code, which runs a command with arguments

```
subprocess.call(["schtasks.exe", "/Query","/V","/FO","csv",">>", r"D:/temp/fo3.csv"])
```

However I am having problems with the `>>` part of the argument, the command does not seem to like it, it gives the following message

```
ERROR Invalid argument /option - >>
```

So my question is how do i get the `>>` argument to work?

Answer (score 4):

when you pass arguments as a list like that, subprocess passes each argument to the program.  What is probably happening is that your program (`schtasks.exe`) is seeing the argument `>>` and it doesn't know what to do with it.  When you run this in the shell, `>>` is interpreted by the shell as redirection and so your program never sees it.

You have 2 options, pass the arguments as a string and use `shell = True`.  This is not recommended if you are accepting user input which can modify the string you're passing to subprocess as it would lead to a security risk in your program.

Your second option is to pass an open file object to `stdout`, e.g.

```
f = open(r"D:/temp/fo3.csv",'a')
subprocess.call(["schtasks.exe", "/Query","/V","/FO","csv"], stdout = f)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your example but on line subprocess.call(["schtasks.exe", "/Query","/V","/FO","csv"], stdout = f) I get the error TypeError: an integer is required. I've tried to add an integer on the 1st line, but still the error appears.

Comment: @HalilSiddique -- Really?  the documentation states the following "Valid values are PIPE, an existing file descriptor (a positive integer), **an existing file object**, and None." -- You could try to pass `f.fileno()` I suppose, but that doesn't seem like it should be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Output redirection (the `>>`) is a shell feature and won't work if you call the program directly. Use `shell=True` in the call.